# Is there Lockdown Mode for Trial Version?

Tags: vmware, mode, esxi, lockdown

I was just wondering if there is the "Lockdown Mode" for trial version of the ESXi 4.1 version? I can't seem to enable to option as when I F2 to customize the system, the option is not selectable and there is no such option found in the vSphere 4.0. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is lockdown mode provided however you will need to use a vCenter functions to enable the lockdown mode on the ESXi server first.